# How to pass the Drop down value as an input to a function to generate dataset within Shiny Dashboard? The dataset uses reactive filters

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shiny-reactivity

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(tidyverse)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

options(dplyr.summarise.inform = FALSE)

header <- dashboardHeader(
    title = "NSCLC Market Share"
)


body <- dashboardBody(
    tags$head(tags$style(
        HTML('.wrapper {height: auto !important; position:relative; overflow-x:hidden; overflow-y:hidden}')
    )),
    fluidRow(
        HTML("<div class='col-sm-4' style='min-width: 900px !important; 
             font-size:10px; color: #404040;'>"),
        tabBox(
            width = NULL,
            title = "MarketShare",
            id = "tabset1", height = "250px",
            tabPanel(
                "Incidence",
                fluidRow(
                    column(6, tableOutput("therapy_tbl")),
                    column(6, plotOutput("therapy_plot", height = "150px"))
                ),
                br(),
                hr(style = "border-color: black;"),
                fluidRow(
                    column(6, tableOutput("pdl1_tbl")),
                    column(6, plotOutput("pdl1_plot", height = "150px"))
                ),
                br(),
                hr(style = "border-color: black;"),
                fluidRow(
                    column(6, tableOutput("pdl1_mono_tbl")),
                    column(6, plotOutput("pdl1_mono_plot", height = "150px"))
                ),
                br(),
                hr(style = "border-color: black;"),
                fluidRow(
                    column(6, tableOutput("pdl1_combo_tbl"))
                )
                
                
            )
            
            ,
            tabPanel("Prevalence", fluidRow(
                column(6, tableOutput("therapy_p_tbl"))
            ))
        )
    )
)



sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(
    radioButtons("datasource", "Select a data source:",
                 c("Flatiron", "Truven Commercial")),
    
    radioButtons("cohort", "Select a cohort:",
                 c("All", "Cohort X")),
    
    checkboxGroupInput("LineFilter", "Select Line Number",
                       choiceNames = list("1L", "2L"),
                       choiceValues = list(1, 2), selected = c(1, 2)
    ),
    
    br(),
    
    fluidRow(
        column(5, checkboxGroupInput("ecogFilter", "Select ECOG",
                                     choiceNames = list("0~1", "2", ">2", "unknown"),
                                     choiceValues = list("0-1","2", ">2", "unknown"),
                                     selected = list("0-1","2", ">2", "unknown")
        )),
        
        column(1, checkboxGroupInput("pdl1Filter", "Select PDL1",
                                     choiceNames = list("unknown", ">=50%", "<1%", "1~49%"),
                                     selected = list("unknown", ">=50%", "< 1%", "1-49%"),
                                     choiceValues = unique(df$gp_pdl1_tps)
        ))
    ),
    br(),
    fluidRow(
        column(5, checkboxGroupInput("egfrFilter", "EGFR Status",
                                     choices = list("positive", "negative", "unknown"),
                                     selected = list("positive", "negative", "unknown"),
                                     choiceValues = list("positive", "negative", "unknown")
        )),
        column(1, checkboxGroupInput("alkFilter", "ALK Status",
                                     choices = list("positive", "negative", "unknown"),
                                     selected = list("positive", "negative", "unknown"),
                                     choiceValues = list("positive", "negative", "unknown")
        ))
    ),
    br(),
    selectInput("year_value", "Select Year:",
                c("2019", "2020", "2021")),
    actionButton("go", "Run")
)





ui <- dashboardPage(
    header,
    sidebar,
    body
)

server = function(input, output) {
    
    filtData_therapy <- reactive({
        
        df %>% 
            filter(gp_pdl1_tps %in% input$pdl1Filter | ( is.na(gp_pdl1_tps) & "" %in% input$pdl1Filter )) %>% 
            filter(gp_ecog %in% input$ecogFilter | ( is.na(value_ecog) & "" %in% input$ecogFilter )) %>% 
            filter(has_egfr %in% input$egfrFilter | ( is.na(has_egfr) & "" %in% input$egfrFilter )) %>%
            filter(has_alk %in% input$alkFilter | ( is.na(has_alk) & "" %in% input$alkFilter )) %>%
            filter(line_number %in% input$LineFilter) %>% 
            group_by(therapy_class, Year_month) %>% 
            summarise(count = n()) %>% 
            full_join(data.frame('therapy_class' = therapy_class), by = c('therapy_class')) 
        
        
    })
    
    
    filtData_therapy_p <- reactive({
        
        dfs %>% 
            filter(gp_pdl1_tps %in% input$pdl1Filter | ( is.na(gp_pdl1_tps) & "" %in% input$pdl1Filter )) %>% 
            filter(gp_ecog %in% input$ecogFilter | ( is.na(value_ecog) & "" %in% input$ecogFilter )) %>% 
            filter(has_egfr %in% input$egfrFilter | ( is.na(has_egfr) & "" %in% input$egfrFilter )) %>%
            filter(has_alk %in% input$alkFilter | ( is.na(has_alk) & "" %in% input$alkFilter )) %>%
            filter(line_number %in% input$LineFilter) %>% 
            group_by(therapy_class, Year_month) %>% 
            summarise(count = n()) %>% 
            full_join(data.frame('therapy_class' = therapy_class), by = c('therapy_class'))
        
        
    })
    
    
    
    filtData_pdl1 <- reactive({
        
        df %>% 
            filter(gp_pdl1_tps %in% input$pdl1Filter) %>% 
            filter(gp_ecog %in% input$ecogFilter) %>%
            filter(line_number %in% input$LineFilter) %>% 
            filter(has_egfr %in% input$egfrFilter | ( is.na(has_egfr) & "" %in% input$egfrFilter )) %>%
            filter(has_alk %in% input$alkFilter | ( is.na(has_alk) & "" %in% input$alkFilter )) %>%
            filter( is.na(pdl1_based) == FALSE) %>% 
            group_by(pdl1_based, Year_month) %>% 
            summarise(count = n())
        
        
    })
    
    filtData_pdl1_mono <- reactive({
        
        df %>% 
            filter(gp_pdl1_tps %in% input$pdl1Filter | ( is.na(gp_pdl1_tps) & "" %in% input$pdl1Filter )) %>% 
            filter(gp_ecog %in% input$ecogFilter | ( is.na(value_ecog) & "" %in% input$ecogFilter )) %>% 
            filter(line_number %in% input$LineFilter) %>%
            filter(has_egfr %in% input$egfrFilter | ( is.na(has_egfr) & "" %in% input$egfrFilter )) %>%
            filter(has_alk %in% input$alkFilter | ( is.na(has_alk) & "" %in% input$alkFilter )) %>%
            filter(pdl1_based %in% c("PD-1/PD-L1 monotherapies")) %>% 
            group_by(line_name, Year_month) %>% 
            summarise(count = n()) %>% 
            full_join(data.frame(line_name = pdl1_based_therapy))
        
        
    })
    
    filtData_pdl1_combo <- reactive({
        
        df %>% 
            filter(gp_pdl1_tps %in% input$pdl1Filter | ( is.na(gp_pdl1_tps) & "" %in% input$pdl1Filter )) %>% 
            filter(gp_ecog %in% input$ecogFilter | ( is.na(value_ecog) & "" %in% input$ecogFilter )) %>% 
            filter(line_number %in% input$LineFilter) %>%
            filter(has_egfr %in% input$egfrFilter | ( is.na(has_egfr) & "" %in% input$egfrFilter )) %>%
            filter(has_alk %in% input$alkFilter | ( is.na(has_alk) & "" %in% input$alkFilter )) %>%
            filter(pdl1_based %in% c("PD-1/PD-L1 + chemo combos (incl. nivo+ipi)")) %>% 
            group_by(line_name, Year_month) %>% 
            summarise(count = n())
        
        
    })
    
    output$therapy_tbl <- renderTable(
        rbind(
            filtData_therapy() %>%
                pivot_wider(names_from = Year_month, values_from = count) %>%
                ungroup(),
            filtData_therapy() %>%
                pivot_wider(names_from = Year_month, values_from = count) %>%
                ungroup() %>%
                summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
                mutate(therapy_class = "Total")) %>% 
            replace(is.na(.), 0),
        spacing = c("xs"), striped = TRUE
    )
    
    output$therapy_p_tbl <- renderTable(
        rbind(
            filtData_therapy_p() %>% 
                pivot_wider(names_from = Year_month, values_from = count) %>% 
                ungroup(),
            filtData_therapy_p() %>% 
                pivot_wider(names_from = Year_month, values_from = count) %>% 
                ungroup() %>%
                summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
                mutate(therapy_class = "Total"))%>% 
            replace(is.na(.), 0),
        spacing = c("xs"), striped = TRUE
    )
    
    output$pdl1_tbl <- renderTable(
        rbind(filtData_pdl1() %>% 
                  pivot_wider(names_from = Year_month, values_from = count) %>% 
                  ungroup(),
              filtData_pdl1() %>% 
                  pivot_wider(names_from = Year_month, values_from = count) %>% 
                  ungroup() %>% 
                  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
                  mutate(pdl1_based = "Total")) %>% 
            replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
            rename("PD-1/PD-L1-based therapies" = pdl1_based),
        spacing = c("xs"), striped = TRUE
        
        
    )
    
    
    output$pdl1_mono_tbl <- renderTable(
        rbind(filtData_pdl1_mono() %>% 
                  pivot_wider(names_from = Year_month, values_from = count) %>% 
                  ungroup() %>% select_if(not_all_na) ,
              filtData_pdl1_mono() %>%
                  pivot_wider(names_from = Year_month, values_from = count) %>% 
                  ungroup() %>% 
                  select_if(not_all_na) %>% 
                  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
                  mutate(line_name = "Total")) %>% 
            replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
            rename("PD-1/PD-L1 monotherapies" = line_name),
        spacing = c("xs"), striped = TRUE
    )
    
    output$pdl1_combo_tbl <- renderTable(
        rbind(filtData_pdl1_combo() %>% 
                  pivot_wider(names_from = Year_month, values_from = count) %>% 
                  ungroup(),
              filtData_pdl1_combo() %>%
                  pivot_wider(names_from = Year_month, values_from = count) %>% 
                  ungroup() %>% 
                  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), sum, na.rm = TRUE)) %>% 
                  mutate(line_name = "Total")) %>% 
            replace(is.na(.), 0) %>% 
            rename("PD-1/PD-L1 + chemo combos (incl. nivo+ipi)" = line_name),
        spacing = c("xs"), striped = TRUE
    )
    
    
    output$therapy_plot <- renderPlot({
        filtData_therapy() %>% 
            pivot_wider(names_from = Year_month, values_from = count) %>%
            ungroup() %>% 
            mutate_if(endsWith(names(.),"2020"),function(x) x / sum(x, na.rm = TRUE) * 100) %>% 
            melt(id=c("therapy_class")) %>% 
            ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value, group = therapy_class, color = therapy_class)) +
            geom_line() + geom_point() + scale_y_continuous(labels = function(x) paste0(x, "%")) +
            cowplot::theme_minimal_hgrid(font_size = 9) + 
            theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title = element_blank(),legend.justification = "center")
    })
    
    output$pdl1_plot <- renderPlot({
        filtData_pdl1() %>% 
            ggplot(aes(x = Year_month, y = count, group = pdl1_based, color = pdl1_based)) +
            geom_line() + geom_point() +
            cowplot::theme_minimal_hgrid(font_size = 9) +
            theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title = element_blank(), legend.justification = "center")
    })
    
    output$pdl1_mono_plot <- renderPlot({
        filtData_pdl1_mono() %>% 
            ggplot(aes(x = Year_month, y = count, group = line_name, color = line_name)) +
            geom_line() + geom_point() +
            cowplot::theme_minimal_hgrid(font_size = 9) +
            theme(legend.position="bottom", legend.title = element_blank(), legend.justification = "center")
    })
    
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I have this shiny dashboard code. I am trying couple of things that are not working.

1. I am running a function (incident, prevalent) to create two datasets. The function takes in Year value and creates dataset with Yearmonth count. I want to pass Year_value input to the function but only when Action button is pressed.

   selectInput("year_value", "Select Year:",
   c("2019", "2020", "2021")),
   actionButton("go", "Run")
2. All the filters are in the sidebar. I am applying filter to the created dataset and then grouping by various groups. For each group I am producing a summary table of counts and a line plot. Since I am filtering based on the inputvalue and grouping by several variables, I am having to create a separate reactive function for each group. Is there a better way to do the filtering and grouping? Also the data that this reactive function takes is based on the function that takes the year input.

Comment: I haven't tested your code (as there was no reproducible data),  Can you just put this in a list and return a list output i.e. `

Comment: `lst_filtData_therapy <- reactive({
      dplyr::lst(df, dfs) %>%
      map(~ .x %>%
                  filter(gp_pdl1_tps %in% input$pdl1Filter | ( is.na(gp_pdl1_tps) & "" %in% input$pdl1Filter )) %>% 
              ....
                  filter(line_number %in% input$LineFilter) %>% 
                  group_by(therapy_class, Year_month) %>% 
                  summarise(count = n()) %>% 
                  full_join(data.frame('therapy_class' = therapy_class), by = c('therapy_class')) 
            )})`

Comment: @akrun I have added sample dataset for df and dfs which can go as the input. The function incident and prevalent uses lot of other helper function and data mapping. df and dfs are generated through those two function. I do want to pass input from dashboard to the function so that the user is able to check the year they wish to. The data is fed with filters to display reactive summary table.

Comment: yeah I have added those inputs for df and dfs

Comment: Thanks, let me test it

Comment: @akrun I have updated the code and it should be working now. Just need to include the df and dfs dataset.

Comment: That is 300 lines of code. Do you think you can reduce the code? Maybe remove the code which is not relevant to your actual question and try to make the example minimal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the eventReactive() to catch the selectInput value when the action button is pressed. Within the eventReative you can pass the user input values to the function. I was able to pass the inputs to the function to create the dataset which was then used in the reactive which used reactive filters.

https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.0.3/observeEvent.html

UI - selectInput

```
                        fluidRow(offset = 2,
                        selectInput("year_value", "Select Year:",
                                    c("2018", "2019", "2020", "2021"),
                                    selected = "2020")),
                    fluidRow(
                        selectInput("month_value", "Select Month:",
                                    choices = list( "January" = 1, "February" = 2, "March" = 3, "April" = 4, "May" = 5, 
                                                    "June" = 6, "July" = 7, "August" = 8, "September" = 9, "October" = 10,
                                                    "November" = 11, "December" = 12),
                                    selected = 1),
                        actionButton("go", "Update")),
                    tags$head(tags$style(HTML(".selectize-input {height: 80%; width: 50%; font-size: 15px;}")))
```

Server - eventReactive and Reactive

```
 server = function(input, output) {
    
    df <- eventReactive(input$go, {
        incident(df_analysis_nsclc, year = input$year_value, month = input$month_value)
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
    
    dfs <- eventReactive(input$go, {
        incident(df_analysis_nsclc, year = input$year_value, month = input$month_value)
    }, ignoreNULL = FALSE)
    
    filtData_therapy <- reactive({
        
        df() %>% 
            filter(gp_pdl1_tps %in% input$pdl1Filter | ( is.na(gp_pdl1_tps) & "" %in% input$pdl1Filter )) %>% 
            filter(gp_ecog %in% input$ecogFilter | ( is.na(value_ecog) & "" %in% input$ecogFilter )) %>% 
            filter(has_egfr %in% input$egfrFilter | ( is.na(has_egfr) & "" %in% input$egfrFilter )) %>%
            filter(has_alk %in% input$alkFilter | ( is.na(has_alk) & "" %in% input$alkFilter )) %>%
            filter(line_number %in% input$LineFilter) %>% 
            group_by(therapy_class, Year_month) %>% 
            summarise(count = n()) %>% 
            full_join(data.frame('therapy_class' = therapy_class), by = c('therapy_class')) 
        
        
    })
```